# Unable to stop mousemove event

Tags: javascript

I've had an idea of coding a game with pure javascript and sass.
But when I start rotating the container cube, I can't stop it.
I tried preventDefault, stopPropagation functions and tried to assign the running event to null but nothing happens.

```
    document.body.onmousedown = function (e) {
        'use strict';
        var x = e.clientX,
            y = e.clientY;
        document.body.onmousemove = function (e) {
            var X = e.clientX - x,
                Y = e.clientY - y;
            console.log('rotateX(' + Math.floor(Y) + 'deg) rotateY(' + Math.floor(X) + 'deg)');
            document.querySelector('main').style.cssText = 'transform:rotateX(' + parseInt(Math.floor(Y)) + 'deg) rotateY(' + parseInt(Math.floor(X)) + 'deg)';

        };
    };
```

Solutions I've tried:

```
document.onmouseup = function () {
    'use strict';
    document.body.onmousemove = function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    };
document.onmouseup = function () {
    'use strict';
    document.body.onmousemove = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
};
document.onmouseup = function () {
    'use strict';
    document.body.onmousemove = function () {
        return;
    };
};
```

Comment: use boolean variables to decide what happens on event start.

Comment: you might want to implement a `onmouseup` event that sets the css class to something that does not transfor/rotate the element?

Comment: could you show how/where you tried to deactivate what event.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Your solutions have `document.onmouseup`. Shouldn't that be `document.body.onmouseup`?

Comment: @DavidKnipe ridiculously that's the problem, I feel silly now, thanks for making it clear :)